# Using endpoints-proto-datastore, how do you pass attributes to a method that are not contained in the EndpointsModel

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am trying to pass attributes into an API call that are not contained in my [EndpointsModel](https://code.google.com/p/endpoints-proto-datastore/source/browse/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/model.py?r=183ab0ff336857e081148ac2fdaa73543ca44452#593). For example, say I have the following model:

```
class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  attr1 = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Then assume I want to pass in `attr2` as a parameter, but I don't want `attr2` to be used as a filter nor do I want it to be stored in the model. I simply want to pass in some string, retrieve it inside of the method and use it to perform some business logic.

The documentation describes the `query_fields` parameter for specifying the fields you want to pass into the method, but these appear to be coupled to the attributes contained inside the model, therefore you cannot pass in attributes that are not specified in the model.

Likewise, the documentation states that you can pass in attributes via the path variable:

```
@MyModel.method(request_fields=('id',),
                path='mymodel/{id}', name='mymodel.get'
                http_method='GET')
def MyModelGet(self, my_model):
  # do something with id
```

But this requires you to change the URL, plus this appears to have the same constraint as `query_fields` (the attribute must exist in the model).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For just this use case, `EndpointsAliasProperty` was [created](https://code.google.com/p/endpoints-proto-datastore/source/browse/endpoints_proto_datastore/ndb/properties.py?r=183ab0ff336857e081148ac2fdaa73543ca44452#90). It acts much like `@property` does in Python in that you can specify a getter, setter and doc, but no deleter is specified in this context.

Since these properties will be sent over the wire and used with Google's API infrastructure, a type must be specified, so we can't just use `@property`. In addition, we need the typical property/field metadata such as `repeated`, `required`, etc.

Its use has been [documented](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/examples/custom_alias_properties.html) in one of the samples, but for your specific use case,

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsAliasProperty
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class MyModel(EndpointsModel):
  attr1 = ndb.StringProperty()

  def attr2_set(self, value):
    # Do some checks on the value, potentially raise
    # endpoints.BadRequestException if not a string
    self._attr2 = value

  @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=attr2_set)
  def attr2(self):
    # Use getattr in case the value was never set
    return getattr(self, '_attr2', None)
```

Since no value for `property_type` was passed to `EndpointsAliasProperty`, the default of `protorpc.messages.StringField` is used. If instead you wanted an integer, you could've instead used:

```
@EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=attr2_set, property_type=messages.IntegerField)
```

Comment: What does that mean? Maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: If I want my property to be read-only, can I just omit the 'setter' property?

Comment: Yes. You also control which methods interact with it, but the setter is really for taking the value from the request and moving it from a protorpc object to an ndb model object.